# Android - Tempo adjust?

Tags: android, c++, c, audio, android-ndk

I have now admitted defeat that you cannot use/build a good audio tempo function without using the NDK as the SoundPool class is buggy and only allows up to 1MB. Now my question is does anyone know of any good tempo/bpm changing code either in a library or some source code for the NDK?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Sample Rate Converter.  [Simple Rabbit Code](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/) is pretty damned good.

If you wish to do more complex things such as time stretching i suggest you start [here](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/).